# How to start a thread if a button is idle?

Tags: java, android

I need a thread to start after 3 seconds of a button being idle, is there a simple way of doing it?

I'm building a counter app, the button triggers two counters, the total counter and the "tapping counter", the tapping counter helps keep track of the actual change of values, showing how many taps the user did, I need it to vanish after some seconds so the user can tap again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for stuffs like that I usually use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) with a [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) in order to do stuff after X `milliseconds` the user isn't doing a specific action.

First, create a `runnable` and a `handler`

```
final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
private Runnable runnable;
private final long DELAY = 3000; // how many milliseconds you want to wait
```

Then add the `onClickListener`:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {        
  }
});
```

Then, inside `onClick` event, remove `callbacks` and istantiate the `handler` again as follows:

```
if(runnable != null) {
  // in this case the user already clicked once at least
  handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override    
  public void run() {
    //this code will run when user isn't clicking for the time you set before.
  }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY);
```

Final result:

```
final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
private Runnable runnable;
private final long DELAY = 3000; // how many milliseconds you want to wait


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // all your previous stuffs


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {       
        if(runnable != null) {
          // in this case the user already clicked once at least
          handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        runnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override    
          public void run() {
            //this code will run when user isn't clicking for the time you set before.
          }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY); 
      }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps, for any question feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

At first, you create a `Timer` with a `TimerTask`(with your Thread) and schedule it to run after 3 seconds.

Every time the button is pressed, you reset the timer.

```
public class MyClass{
    private Timer timer=new Timer()
    private TimerTask task=new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            //your action
        }
    };
    public void init(){
        timer.schedule(task,3000);
    }
    public void onButtonClick(){
        task.cancel();
        timer.schedule(task,3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handler may work in this scenario, with a 3000 milisecond delay.

`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // do action
        }
    }, 3000);`

Comment: you have to stop it on every click, or it will just start a handler for every click without considering whether the user is still clicking or not